# When is a slab said to be in a steady state?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity

> The steady state is distinct from thermal equilibrium for which the temperature at any position of a slab must be the same.

Could anyone explain this line to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A thermal conductor is said to be in steady state when it **cannot absorb any more  heat that is applied to it**. In other words, you can say that the body is "saturated" with heat energy, and whatever heat it will receive after attaining the steady state, will be conducted through the body, and not absorbed by it.

Equilibrium is the condition when the **temperature throughout the body is the same**, and hence it'll **no longer conduct heat at that temperature**, unless the temperature of either end is changed, and the equilibrium is disturbed.

Steady state determines whether the body would absorb any more heat. Equilibrium determines whether the body will conduct any more heat.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler (and more concise) answer than this is that, at steady state, the temperature at all locations within the slab is not changing with time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you ask about a slab, assume the same thermal conductivity throughout. When there is a temperature difference between both sides of the slab, heat will flow through the slab. In steady state that flow will be the same everywhere and the temperature gradient will be constant and independent of time.